# Decomposition space (D,U) of X is $T_1$ or not?

Tags: general-topology

This question is from my Topology assignment and I was unable to solve this particular problem.

> Let (X,T) be a $T_1$ space and let (D,U) be a decomposition space of X. Prove that (D,U) is $T_1$ iff each member of D is a closed subset of X.

I am sorry but I can't provide much attempt for this problem.

Let (D,U) is $T_1$ , then I am unable to see which result I can use to prove that each member of D is a closed subset of X. I also tried taking some elements to be open but unable to get a contradiction.

Similarly, for converse I am not able to make any progress.

Kindly bear with me to give some hints.

Answer (score 1):

$Y$ is $T_1$ iff every singletons is closed.

Then for a member $D$ of $\mathcal D$ we have $q^{-1}[\{D\}]= D$ etc.

Comment: Given  Each member of D is a closed subset of X implies that (D,U) is $T_1$ is clear to me but I am unable to prove the other part ie let (D,U) is $T_1$ but I am unable to prove that if $X_i \in D$ then proving that $X/X_i$ is open , but I was unable to think how to use $T_1$ to prove that.Can you please help?

Comment: @James if $D$ is a member of $\mathcal D$ then $\{D\}$ is closed in the decomposition space iff $q^{-1}[\{D\}] = D$ is closed in $X$. You don’t need complements, as closedness can be tested directly.